# Cannot connect to AD DC over VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, ping

I have a Windows 2016 server acting as a AD DC. I have Fortigate 50E firewall. I'm setting up a VPN connection for remote users on the Fortigate.

VPN connects fine. I'm able to ping every other host in the internal network, except the DC. The DC has also the DNS server, so I'm using IPs for now. We even have another Windows 2016 server joined to the same domain and I can ping that.

I've checked the firewall rules on the DC and tried also disabling the firewall. Still the same. Cannot ping, cannot access file shares, DNS or any service on the DC. Accessing other servers/Workstations works fine.

The configuration on the Fortigate has nothing that would be specific to this single IP address.

I'm out of ideas. What else could block the connections on the DC?

Comment: If you do a traceroute to the DC where does it fail?  Can you ping the VPN ip of a connected client **from the DC**?  What happens if you attempt to traceroute to vpn ip of a connected VPN client?

Comment: Traceroute would have two steps, the internal network GW and then the DC. GW ok, DC timeout. Tested this also with the other internal network IPs and traceroute goes through. Not able to ping to the other direction, but this is not even supported by the routing on the Fortigate.

Comment: Tested also assigning the IP of the DC temporarily to a workstation. I was able to ping the workstation even when it was using the IP of the DC. Conclusion, the DC must be self somehow rejecting the connections.

Answer (score 0):

In "Default Domain Controller Policy" do you have anything setup for

Computer Configuration>Policies>Windows Settings>Security Settings>Local Policies>User Rights Assignment

for the settings labeled "Access Computer From the Network",  "Allow Log On Locally",  or  "Allow Logon Through Remote Desktop Services"?

Comment: "Access Computer From Network": everyone. "Allow Log On Locally": Administrators. "Allow Logon Through Remote Desktop Services"  is in not defined state. However, I'd assume that user rights assignments don't really affect PING?

Comment: Correct. I had a similar issue with a Sophos firewall one time and the problem turned out to be LDAP related. The domain enforced encryption but the firewall was configured for unencrypted auth. By default LDAP binds in AD aren't encrypted, so maybe you have the reverse issue? (Firewall set to encrypted but GPO is not?) That also wouldn't stop pings, but I've also seen machines with extreme uptime do strange things like that. Perhaps a restart would help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have this issue any longer, but in case someone else does.

It does not sound like a firewall issue. I would be willing to bet it is because network discovery is turned off.

GO TO:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings

Expand the currently used one, which should be Domain but it may not. Ensure that the radio button for Turn on network discovery is enabled. If it is not, click it then click Save Changes.
***Important- go back and check to see if it is still enabled. If not one or more of the following dependent services are disabled:

- DNS Client
- Function Discovery Resource Publication
- SSDP Discovery
- UPnP Device Host

Go to Services- Click Start and type in services.msc
Those services should say Running in the status column. If not open up the service by double clicking or right clicking and selecting properties.
Set Startup Type to Automatic in the drop down and click Apply. Now click Start to start the service.

Once you are sure all the listed services are running go back and turn Network Discovery back on, exit, then go back and double check that it is enabled.

Once Network Discovery is turned on it will allow for you to ping the DC.
Hope this helps you or the next person that reads it :)